# How to use bootstrap in a loop?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

I made a blog in php and i want to use bootstrap to devide my posts like this [Bootstrap Jumbotron example](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/jumbotron/)

My code for generating posts is:

```
try {
    $stmt = $db->query('SELECT postID, postTitle, postDesc, postDate FROM blog_posts ORDER BY postID DESC');
    while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
        echo '<div>';
        echo '<h1><a href="viewpost.php?id='.$row['postID'].'">'.$row['postTitle'].'</a></h1>';
        echo '<p>Posted on '.date('jS M Y H:i:s', strtotime($row['postDate'])).'</p>';
        echo '<p>'.$row['postDesc'].'</p>';
        echo '<p><a href="viewpost.php?id='.$row['postID'].'">Read More</a></p>';
        echo '</div>';
    }
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

How to format this loop to look like the example?

Comment: Just `echo` the `div` with `col-md-4`.

Comment: @b0s3 That simple? OMG I was reading the internet for 2 hours :)). THX it is working :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how many you want per row: you can use col-sm-4 col-sm-3 or col-md-3 or col-md-4

```
 //to have 3 on the same line
 echo '<div class="col-sm-4">';
     echo '<h2><a href="viewpost.php?id='.$row['postID'].'">'.$row['postTitle'].'</a></h2>';
     echo '<p>Posted on '.date('jS M Y H:i:s', strtotime($row['postDate'])).'</p>';
     echo '<p>'.$row['postDesc'].'</p>';             
     echo '<p><a role="button" href="#" class="btn btn-default" href="viewpost.php?id='.$row['postID'].'">Read More</a></p>';               
 echo '</div>';


//to have 4 on the same line
echo '<div class="col-sm-3">';
     echo '<h2><a href="viewpost.php?id='.$row['postID'].'">'.$row['postTitle'].'</a></h2>';
     echo '<p>Posted on '.date('jS M Y H:i:s', strtotime($row['postDate'])).'</p>';
     echo '<p>'.$row['postDesc'].'</p>';             
     echo '<p><a role="button" href="#" class="btn btn-default" href="viewpost.php?id='.$row['postID'].'">Read More</a></p>';               
echo '</div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        echo '<div class="col-md-4">';
            echo '<h2><a href="viewpost.php?id='.$row['postID'].'">'.$row['postTitle'].'</a></h2>';
            echo '<p>Posted on '.date('jS M Y H:i:s', strtotime($row['postDate'])).'</p>';
            echo '<p>'.$row['postDesc'].'</p>';             
            echo '<p><a role="button" href="#" class="btn btn-default" href="viewpost.php?id='.$row['postID'].'">Read More</a></p>';               
        echo '</div>';
```